# Hide scrollbar not working in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I have used `::-webkit-scrollbar` & -`ms-overflow-style: none` to hide scrollbar. It is working fine with Chrome & IE but **not in Firefox**. Any solution with CSS or Jquery? Please see the added snippet below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var count;
    var interval;

    $("#hoverscroll").on('mouseover', function() {
        var div = $('.box');

        interval = setInterval(function(){
            count = count || 1;
            var pos = div.scrollTop();
            div.scrollTop(pos + count);
        }, 10);
    }).click(function() {
        if (count < 6) {
             count = count+1;
        }
    }).on('mouseout', function() {
        // Uncomment this line if you want to reset the speed on out
        // count = 0;
        clearInterval(interval);
    });
})
;
```

```css
.con {
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 position: relative;
}
.box {
 width: 100%;
 max-height: 300px;
 background: #eee;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 -ms-overflow-style: none;
}
.box::-webkit-scrollbar {
 display: none;
}
.box::-moz-scrollbar {
 overflow-y: hidden;
}
#hoverscroll {
 width: 100%;
 height: 40px;
 background-color: gray;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<div class="con">
  <div class="box"> content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
  </div>
  <div id="hoverscroll"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: note: `::-webkit-scrollbar` applies to webkit based borwsers (webkit prefix is the clue) `-ms-overflow-style: none` applies to microsoft based browsers (ms prefix is the clue) ... of course firefox doesn't understand css written for chrome or IE/Edge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No cross-browser solution. Wrap it in a smaller tag and then add "overflow:hidden" for that tag.

Comment: overflow: hidden not a suitable solution for me.. because, it contains vertical dropdown menu. Check the categories section in this link: 
   https://aawkitchens.com/

Comment: You cannot make jquery / css go your way. Rather you have to accept what they offer. Like I said, there is no cross-browser solution for your problem.

Comment: Check out this link: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kurlak/2013/11/03/hiding-vertical-scrollbars-with-pure-css-in-chrome-ie-6-firefox-opera-and-safari/